# Can I convert a packaged active flow into an active flow template in a 1GP managed package?

Tags: screen-flow, versioning, 1gp-package

We have a flow, packaged in our AppExchange 1GP managed package. We want to convert this to a flow template in a new major/minor package release.

Before we try to do this, I wanted to see if anyone knows if this is permitted - it seems reasonable (since we are effectively relaxing constraints around the flow, rather than trying to tighten them) but we've seen other on-the-face-of-it "reasonable" changes being disallowed in the context of 1GPs.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question on the partner forums and got the following answer from a Salesforce employee:

> This is allowed - I have recently tested this with an active flow in a 1GP. Changing it to a template or overridable will require you to "Save As" a new version of the flow in your packaging org. No issues installing/upgrading in my experience or that I'm aware of.

It is worth noting that, as of the time of writing this answer, it is not possible to create flow versions in a patch org for 1GP, which means this change cannot be done in a patch release.